# Amazon EC2 MS SQL Instances

Tags: sql-server, amazon-ec2, sql-server-2008-r2

We have an Amazon EC2 box running the Windows Server 2008 with MS SQL Server 2008 R2. The default instance of the SQL server is running fine (the default MSSQLSERVER), we want to add a second one - when we go to the the set up and configuration (the SQL Server Installation Center) it asks for Installation Media folder.

Does anyone know if we can get it (or if we can)? We have tried looking for drives to mount that possibly had the installation on, but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the ability to create multiple instances is not included with the licensing provided by Amazon/Microsoft when using the SQL Server EC2 instance type.  I went through the list of public snapshots on US-EAST, and there's no public media snapshot available for SQL Server (there is for the operating system discs, though.)

Another person [asked about this on their support site](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=172347&#172347), but Amazon didn't respond to the post and the conclusion was that it wasn't available.

If you have access to a physical (or the files contained on a) SQL Server 2008 R2 disc, you could upload it yourself (there's currently no charge for inbound bandwidth to AWS).  This may be a violation of the software license, though.  You'd have to ask Amazon about that (but you may not get an answer without their Premium Support package.)

Answer (score 2):

Amazon has a private snapshot of the install media which they will share, on request.  However, such a request may need to be made using premium support.

Comment: A note about premium support: you can sign up for just one month at the lowest ($50) level, then cancel it after the support request. Helps keep it cheap.

Answer (score -1):

Please check for public media snapshot available for SQL Server :

Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 with SQL Server Express - ami-0b887d60

Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 with SQL Server Express and IIS - ami-77d0251c

these are the two ami's with sql express